# How to avoid infinite layoutSubviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, layout, calayer, subview

I have a UITableViewCell subclass which overrides layoutSubviews to apply a fade effect to a webview. For the most part it works fine, but sometimes it ends up in a state where layoutSubvies is called constantly with alternating values for the content height for the webview.

Is there some other place I could apply this gradient to avoid this issue?

```
CAGradientLayer* gradientLayer = nil;
int webViewHeight = 0;

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    NSLog(@"layoutSubviews %f", self.webView.scrollView.contentSize.height);

    [super layoutSubviews];

    if (self.webView.scrollView.contentSize.height == webViewHeight) {
        // nothing has changed
        return;
    }

    if (gradientLayer != nil) {
        [gradientLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
        gradientLayer = nil;
    }

    // if cell height is less than web view height we must fade
    if (self.frame.size.height < self.webView.scrollView.contentSize.height) {
        webViewHeight = self.webView.scrollView.contentSize.height;
        gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];

        NSObject* fadeColor = (NSObject*)[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:.9].CGColor;
        NSObject* transparentColor = (NSObject*)[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.0].CGColor;

        gradientLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:transparentColor, fadeColor, nil];
        gradientLayer.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                               [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.5],
                               [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], nil];

        gradientLayer.bounds = self.bounds;
        gradientLayer.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;

        [self.layer addSublayer:gradientLayer];
    }
}
```

Comment: `layoutSubviews` should only ever do one thing - adjust the bounds/frames of a view's subviews. That's it. No other changes of any kind should be done there.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks for your comment. Is there another place suitable for the gradient?

Comment: You only want the layer added once. Add it in the `init...` method. Only adjust its size in `layoutSubviews`.

Comment: layoutSubviews called every time. so if you change frame or something then it will not work

Answer (score 0):

my TWO cents for similar issue. Hope can help others.
After debugging a little, I noted ALSO adding CALayer will re-invoke layoutSubviews

So if You call:

```
    self.layer.addSublayer(anotherLayer)
```

you wil be re-called in layoutSubviews.